# How to efficiently initialize huge sparse arrays in Julia?

Tags: julia

There are two ways one can initialize a NXN sparse matrix, whose entries are to be read from one/multiple text files. **Which one is faster?** I need the more efficient one, as N is large, typically 10^6.

1). I could store the (x,y) indices in arrays x, y, the entries in an array v and declare

`K = sparse(x,y,value);`

2). I could declare
`K = spzeros(N)`

then read of the (i,j) coordinates and values v and insert them as
`K[i,j]=v;`

as they are being read.
I found no tips about this on Julia’s page on sparse arrays.

Comment: How are you making out with this btw?  Did you try using System Time statements with both of your concepts to get base working times for each?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don’t insert values one by one: that will be tremendously inefficient since the storage in the sparse matrix needs to be reallocated over and over again.

You can also use BenchmarkTools.jl to verify this:

```
julia> using SparseArrays

julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> I = rand(1:1000, 1000); J = rand(1:1000, 1000); X = rand(1000);

julia> function fill_spzeros(I, J, X)
         x = spzeros(1000, 1000)
         @assert axes(I) == axes(J) == axes(X)
         @inbounds for i in eachindex(I)
           x[I[i], J[i]] = X[i]
         end
         x
       end
fill_spzeros (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @btime sparse($I, $J, $X);
  10.713 μs (12 allocations: 55.80 KiB)

julia> @btime fill_spzeros($I, $J, $X);
  96.068 μs (22 allocations: 40.83 KiB)
```

Original post can be found [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/efficient-initialization-of-huge-sparse-arrays/28691)